# How can I make this plugin does not exceed the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

On the right side there is a slider (slider WPRS) that I've installed it.

This plugin is responsible ... the only problem that I have is that the very small resolutions, it exceeds the screen.

Look at the picture below to better understand what I mean.

[image]

**CODE HTML + CSS:**

```
<div class="right">

   <div id="wprs_slider">
       <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
          <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 345px;">
             <ul class="bxslider clearfix" style="width: 415%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-844px, 0px, 0px);">
                 <li style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 422px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/STICLAhh.png" alt="Test" title="Test"><div class="bx-caption"><span>Test</span></div></li>    
                 //other elements li
            </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
.bx-wrapper {
max-width: 100%!important;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

It should work, I guess